# Not able to get value at td class using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I am new to web development and one thing that is driving my head mad is that I am unable to get the value for one of the values in my table.

At present this is my code:

```
<?php
...
if(($result->num_rows)>0){
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        print
        "<tr>".
            "<td id='numbers' class='col-md-4 text-center'>{$row["number"]}</td>".
            "<td class='col-md-1 text-center'>$row["names"]</td>".
        "</tr>";
    }
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
        var jz = $('#numbers').val();
        alert(jz);
</script>
```

I am using bootstrap so I am probably not setting the `ID` properly for the `td` tag. Nothing is being returned for the `#numbers`. I don't get why

Would mean a lot if someone could help me out

Thanks

Comment: Post the rendered HTML. And a related note, IDs **must** be unique and you're duplicating them in your loop.

Comment: .val() is used to get the value attribute. Shortcut for .attr('value')

Answer (score 0):

It's not `.val()`, use `.text()` or `.html()` instead. `.val()` is used on input fields like `textarea`.

http://api.jquery.com/val/

http://api.jquery.com/text/

Code for the question below:

```
$index = 1;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    print
    "<tr>".
        "<td id='numbers".$index."' class='col-md-4 text-center'>{$row["number"]}</td>".
        "<td class='col-md-1 text-center'>$row["names"]</td>".
    "</tr>";
    $index += 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so how do I set the value for one of these ids?

Comment: $("#numbers").text('whatever you want'); It's described in the docs. Also use class names instead of ids or give the ids unique indexes like `id="numbers1"`, `id="numbers2"`

Comment: yeah i was gonna ask, how do I give each select box a unique id? i want to retrieve the value AT each one